# Prove that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^2 |a_n| R^{n-2}$ converges.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am reading "Lectures on Complex Function Theory" by Takaaki Nomura.

The author uses the following proposition in this book without a proof.

> Let $\rho$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$.
> Let $0 < R < \rho$.
> Then, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n^2 |a_n| R^{n-2}$ converges.

If we differentiate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n z^n$ two times, then we get $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n (n - 1) a_n z^{n-2}$ and its radius of convergence is $\rho$.
So, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n (n - 1) |a_n| R^{n-2}$ converges.
But I cannot prove $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n^2 |a_n| R^{n-2}$ converges.
Please tell me a proof if the above proposition is true.

---

By Cauchy-Hadamard's theorem, $\limsup_{n\to \infty} (n (n-1) |a_n|)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \limsup_{n\to \infty} (n^2 |a_n|)^{\frac{1}{n}}$.
So, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n^2 |a_n| R^{n-2}$ converges.
Is this argument ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ satisfy $R<R_1<R_2<\rho$. The series $\sum_n a_nR_2^n$ converges, so $(|a_nR_2^n|)$
is bounded above by $C$ say. Now
$$|n^2a_n R^{n-2}|=\frac{n^2}{R^2}\left(\frac{R}{R_1}\right)^n
\left(\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right)^n|a_nR_2^n|.$$
The sequence
$$\frac{n^2}{R^2}\left(\frac{R}{R_1}\right)^n$$
converges to zero, so is bounded by $C_1$ say. Then
$$|n^2a_n R^{n-2}|\le CC_1\left(\frac{R_1}{R_2}\right)^n,$$
enough to show that $\sum n^aa_nR^{n-2}$ converges, by comparison to the geometric series.

Comment: Angina Seng, Thank you very much for your very original proof.